# Iterating some results from api and database and matching

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I want to iterate results and also iterate movies at the same time not like I'm doing, and pass the movie object only if it matches, because sometimes I get undefined.

code:

```js
{results.map((result) => (
        <Thumbnail
          key={result.id}
          result={result}
          movie={movies.find((movie) => movie.tmdb_id === result.id)}
        />
      ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another component to filter the data first then pass it down to your thumbnail component like this:

```
function YourFunction(props){
return(
  <ul>
    {
     results
     .filter(result => result.id = {props.id})
     .map(movie => <Thumbnail key={movie.id} result={movie} />
    }
  </ul>
   )
}
```

Comment: i mean it exists what do you mean

Comment: This returns blank screen

Comment: I mean you said the value could be `undefined` in which case it will be falsy, so the if statement will ignore it. It may not show because of the braces.

Comment: I have changed the answer. try this..ive not tested though.